# Jsp don't add header

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jsp

Rest web service is work with Postman. But don't work with jsp. I tried with Javascript. But don't work. I'm waiting for your help. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<%@page import="com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Request" %>
<%@ page
        import="org.apache.http.*,com.burakmollaoglu.DEMO.HMAC,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,com.squareup.okhttp.*,java.net.URL, java.util.*" %>
<form action="api/echo" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    Message: <input type="text" name="message">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<br>
<table>
    <%
        long CurrentMillisecond = System.currentTimeMillis();
        out.println(CurrentMillisecond);
        HMAC hmac = new HMAC();
        String CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted = hmac.hmacCrypto(String.valueOf(CurrentMillisecond), "DEMO", "HmacSHA1");
        out.println(CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted);


        request.addHeader("CurrentMillisecond", CurrentMillisecond);
        request.addHeader("CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted", CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted);
        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
            out.print("<tr><td>" + paramName + "</td>\n");
            String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);
            out.println("<td> " + paramValue + "</td></tr>\n");
        }
    %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

*Here is the screenshot:*
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "don't work"? Putting business logic in scriptlets in JSP is bad practice. Put this code in a separate Java class.

Comment: headers is null

Comment: I do not understand your code. `request` is an implicit JSP object that the Container makes available. Is an instance of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest which is a read-only interface. You can not modify content or header. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html `request.addHeader` does not exist. How are you compiling the code?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Path("echo")
public class MyService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Wrong way";
    }
    @POST
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getMessage(@Context HttpHeaders headers,String message){
        String CurrentMillisecondString=null;
        String CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted=null;

        if(headers.getRequestHeader("currentmillisecond")!=null)
            CurrentMillisecondString=headers.getRequestHeader("CurrentMillisecond").get(0);
        if(headers.getRequestHeader("CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted")!=null)
            CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted=headers.getRequestHeader("CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted").get(0);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CurrentMillisecondString+CurrentMillisecondEncyreptedString;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String headerValue = "";
        return Response.status(200).entity("CurrentMillisecondString:"+CurrentMillisecondString+"\n"+"CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted:"+CurrentMillisecondEncyrepted).build();
    }  
}
```